# How to get AutoRest to split out API's by controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rest-client, auto-generate, autorest

Right now I am using:

```
AutoRest\AutoRest.exe -Input %jsonUrl% -Namespace %projectName%ClientAutoGen -OutputDirectory %projectName%Client
```

To generate my `ASP.NET Core` `Rest Client`.

The annoyance is that `AutoRest` creates a single `file/class` for all of the `controllers` in that `API`. I've used `pre-ASP.NET Core` `auto-generators` that would split out each `controller` into their own `file/class`, is there any way to force this behavior in `AutoRest`?

Answer (score 3):

According to the helpful answer by the AutoRest team on GitHub (here: https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/1497 ) the answer is to use an `_` in the OperationId where you want the split to happen. This is my version of the `Filter`:

```
public class SwashbuckleOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var pathSegments = context.ApiDescription.RelativePath.Split(new[] { '/' }).ToList();

            var version = string.Empty;
            var controller = string.Empty;
            if (pathSegments.Count > 1)
            {
                version = pathSegments[0];
                controller = pathSegments[1] + "_";

                pathSegments = pathSegments.Skip(2).Where(x => !x.Contains("{")).ToList();
            }

            string httpMethod = FirstCharToUpper(context.ApiDescription.HttpMethod);
            var routeName = context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor?.AttributeRouteInfo?.Name ?? string.Empty;

            operation.OperationId = $"{version}{controller}{httpMethod}{string.Join("", pathSegments)}{routeName}";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Are you missing the [Route(\"v1/[controller]/\")] on your Controller?", ex);
        }
    }

    private string FirstCharToUpper(string input)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            return string.Empty;

        input = input.Trim().ToLower();

        return input.First().ToString().ToUpper() + new string(input.Skip(1).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Used like this in the `StartUp`:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.OperationFilter<SwashbuckleOperationFilter>();
    //...
}
```

To turn an `API Controller Method` like this:

```
[Route("v1/[controller]/")]
public class ThingController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("ById/{id}")]
    [Produces(typeof(ThingDTO))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetThing([FromRoute] long id)
    {
        // Your implementation
    }
}
```

Into this kind of generated `service method`:

```
public class ThingClient : IThingClient
{
    private readonly AppSettings appSettings;
    private readonly IMapper mapper;
    private IV1Thing api;

    public ThingClient(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettingsOptions, IMapper mapper)
    {
        appSettings = appSettingsOptions.Value;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    private IV1Thing service => api ??
                (api = new V1Thing(new ThingService(new Uri(appSettings.URLs.ThingService))));

    public async Task<IThing> GetByIdAsync(long thingId)
    {
        return mapper.Map<IThing>(await service.GetByIdAsync(thingId));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work with .net core 2.1, in my controllers I have a SwaggerOperationAttribute defined.

```
    public class SwashbuckleOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor controllerActionDescriptor)
        {
            operation.OperationId = $"{controllerActionDescriptor.ControllerName}_{operation.OperationId}";
        }
    }

}
```